# Normalizing values in a curve_fit of Plancks Law from data set *Edit*

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a large set of data that in terms of Intensity counts and Wavelength that I want fit with Planks Law to determine the guess parameter for Temperature.

The Data set is imported as a text file

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

with open('Good_SolarRun2.txt') as g:
    data = g.read()
data = data.split('\n')
Wavle2 = [float(row.split()[0]) for row in data]   # Wavelength (nm)
Int2 = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data]  # Intensity (counts)
```

So I now define the fitting model for Planks Law (In terms of wavelength)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

--- As recommend by user Evert, I set the constants to equal 1 since the optimization for small numbers on a computer is difficult.

```
from scipy.constants import h,k,c

def Plancks_Law(lamb, T):
    return 1/np.power(lamb,5.0) * 1/( np.exp( 1/(lamb*T)) - 1 )
```

So now, I go about setting up the curve_fit configuration with my data set.

```
x = Wavle2

# This has the same shape as Wavle2, but these values are scaled by me.
# Also the same shape as Int2
y = np.array(Intscale2P)

p0_R = (500.) 
optR, pcovR = curve_fit(Plancks_Law, x, y, p0_R)
T_R = optR
T_Rp = pcovR
yM = Plancks_Law(x, T_R)
```

`print T_R` returns the value of `542.04628177`

Which is some unknown units. I'm now stumped on how to convert everything to it correct units. Especially the values in the exponent to the correct units.

Any way on correcting this?

Comment: `a` and `b` might be too small for a decent fit. Try factoring these out of your fit function as well, or equating them to 1 and renormalize after the fit. A fit generally works best if both x, y and fitted-y are of order 1; otherwise you may run into machine precision issues.

Comment: @Evert, let me see if I can work my magic.

Comment: @Evert Good suggestion, now the tricky part is just converting everything. You were help nevertheless. You can submit an answer and I will upload it if you'd like.

Comment: Actually in all honesty, I don't know where to begin with normalizing this. Should I ask it as another question?

Comment: You can rephrase the current question (and possibly adjust the code to your new attempts). Don't forget to update the title as you deem necessary.

Comment: Note that explicitly setting parameters to `float32` probably won't help with the accuracy. Then again, these may or may not be cast automatically to `float64` under the hood, depending on the implementation of `curve_fit` (though I suspect that the actual underlying Fortran routine uses 32 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a slightly finicky issue here: depending on your x values (wavelengths), the exponent, `1/(lamb*T)` can often be too large to be evaluated, and you'll get an overflow. (Or too small, and it will always result in zero.

It might be good to try and split your Planck function into three parts:

- a part where `lamb * T` is large, say > 100. You can then use Rayleigh-Jeans approximation.
- a part where `lamb * T` is small, say < 1e-4. You can then use the Wien approximation.
- for the intermediate part, use the function itself.

That should prevent overflows.

---

To get good fit results, it's desirable to not let parameters and data results run into machine limits, either too large or too small. Since fitting often results in intermediate results well outside the input (parameter or data) range, you're safest off it everything is of order unity (this is simply the result of ["(hu)man(s) being the measure of all things"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protagoras), and computers are made by and for humans).

Starting with the original Planck function:

```
alpha = 2*h*c*c
beta = h*c/k
return alpha/np.power(lamb,5.0) * 1/( np.exp( beta/(lamb*T)) - 1 )
```

Note that alpha is just a normalization. Leave it out here, and apply it at the end, to your fit results. During the fitting, you won't have any large or small alpha value there, just `1`. That one is straightforward.

For beta, you can't really do this: you can't mode it outside the exponential, and apply it after the fact. That's what the three-part function above is for, to circumvent issues there.

You can (and possibly should), though, also normalize your x-values. Let's say your input is of order 1e-9, so nanometers expressed in meters. Make nanometers your unit, and multiply all values by 1e9. Now the x input values are of order unity.

Of course, that means your alpha will change; there's a `lambd**-5` factor there, so if `lambd` goes up by 1e9, then here things change by `1/1e-(9*5) = 1e45`. Factor the 1e45 into alpha.

For beta there is something similar: you multiply `beta` with 1e9.

Finally, you could also attempt to "normalize" `T`. 5000 isn't that far from order unity, but you could turn it int 5, and put the factor 1000 that into `beta`.
Also, put `alpha` and `beta` *outside* the function: they are essentially constants, and need not be evaluated each time the function is called. That makes the fitting faster.

Note: if you remove alpha from the function, and use it only after the fitting, don't forget to take it out of the Wien and Rayleigh-Jeans approximations as well. As stated below: test (e.g., manually compare the results around the region where you go from one formulation to the other, and see that it matches. Or simply draw the curve across a wide range on a log-log plot)!

---

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, and may have gotten signs wrong. Triple check that you need 1e45 and not 1e-45, and ditto for 1e9 or 1e-9. Easy check: put in some decent numbers with wavelength in meters, see what flux you get, then put in wavelength in nanometers with the additional factors, and see if you get the same flux.

Also: grab a piece of paper and work the changes out, step by step. Do that here, and you can apply the same methodology for other functions and fitting problems as well.